# Duplicate result in a switch loop function

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, switch-statement, credit-card

I want to check which company the cards belong to. The result is right, but I don't want to have array result with duplicates.
Example
"Visa" should only appear once time.

Thanks

```js
const Alex = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
const Eva = [5, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 3, 3, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3];
const Scott = [5, 3, 8, 2, 0, 1, 9, 7, 7, 2, 8, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4];
const Michelle = [4, 9, 2, 9, 8, 7, 7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 0, 9, 3];

const people = [Alex, Eva, Scott, Michelle];

const idInvalidCardCompanies = arr1 => {
  const companies = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    switch (arr1[i][0]) {
      case 3:
        companies.push('Amex (American Express)');
        break;
      case 4:
        companies.push('Visa');
        break;
      case 5:
        companies.push('Mastercard');
        break;
      case 6:
        companies.push('Discover');
        break;
      default:
        return 'Company not found';
        break;
    }
  }
  return companies;
}
console.log(idInvalidCardCompanies(people));
```

Comment: You could make `companies` a `Set` instead of an array. Then it can't have duplicates. Otherwise, just check if the array already includes the company before adding it, with `if (!companies.incluedes(...)) { companies.push(...); }`

Answer (score 0):

As [`Barmar`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) said, You can use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) object which lets you store unique values of any type.

Demo as per your code **:**

```js
let companies = new Set();

companies.add('Visa');
companies.add('Mastercard');
companies.add('Mastercard');
companies.add('Visa');

console.log(companies.size); // returns 2 instead of 4

companies.forEach(val => {
  console.log(val);
});
```